# jQuery change form action based on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, pug

I am trying to change the form action in my jade file based on the button click, "Save" and "Delete".

```
form(method='post', id='updateForm')
        label Course Number
        input(type='text', name='courseNum', value= courses[0].courseNum)
        br
        label Course Name
        input(type='text', name='courseName', value= courses[0].courseName
        br
        button#btnSave(type='button') SAVE
        button#btnDelete(type='button') DELETE

script.
    $('#btnDelete').click(function(){
        var action = $(this).val() == '/course/delete/'+courses[0].courseId;
        $('#updateForm').attr('action', action);
        $('#updateForm').submit();
    });
    $('#btnSave').click(function(){
        var action = $(this).val() == '/course/update/' + courses[0].courseId;
        $('#updateForm').attr('action', action);
        $('#updateForm').submit();
    });
```

The input value (courses item) is passed correctly so I assume that in the script it is also  passed correctly. But, why the form is not submitting? There are no actions shown.

Does my script is not correct? What is the best way to change form action?

Thanks.

Comment: your "action" will return a boolean, true/false and you can't set it as form action. What are you expecting to do here: var action = $(this).val() == '/course/delete/'+courses[0].courseId; ?

Comment: What does console shows you?

Comment: in var action = $(this).val() == '/course/delete/'+courses[0].courseId;, I am trying to set the form action to: /course/delete/1 <- 1 is the courseId, that will call app.post('/course/delete/:id', ...);

Comment: Im just trying different solution to change the form action.. And this is my last try, and still, not working.

Comment: Ok, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK try the following:

```
var submitForm = function(method){
    //set form action based on the method passed in the click handler, update/delete
    var formAction = '/course/' + method + '/' + courses[0].courseId;
    //set form action
    $('#updateForm').attr('action', formAction);
    //submit form
    $('#updateForm').submit();
};

$(document)
.on('click', '#btnDelete', function(){
    //set your method - delete
    submitForm('delete');
})
.on('click', '#btnSave', function(){
    //set your method - update
    submitForm('update');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This helped me for solving the problem. Still, this not submit the form. So I put alert per line and I found out the passed courses[0].courseId is undefined. So I stored it in an hidden input in the body, and get the value of that input and stored in a script variable. And, done! Thanks for helping me! @LShetty. :))

Comment: This did it for me too, I had similar issue and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is on this line:

`var action = $(this).val() == '/course/delete/'+courses[0].courseId;`

Here the first equals (=) will assign the part on the right to the variable action. All good there. The **double** equals (==) however is testing whether $(this).val() **is equal to** the string on the right ('/course/delete/'+courses[0].courseId;).

**It seems you are assigning a boolean to action.** If you want to concatenate the string you need something like this:

`var action = $(this).val() + '/course/delete/' + courses[0].courseId;`

If that's what you are trying to do. If not then post an error message and we can help more.

Answer (score -1):

```
form(method='post', id='updateForm')
        label Course Number
        input(type='text', name='courseNum', value= courses[0].courseNum)
        br
        label Course Name
        input(type='text', name='courseName', value= courses[0].courseName
        br
        button#btnSave(type='button') SAVE
        button#btnDelete(type='button') DELETE
```

script.

```
 $('#btnDelete').click(function(){
        var action = $(this).val() == '/course/delete/'+courses[0].courseId;
        $('#updateForm').attr('action', action);
        $('#updateForm').submit();
    });
$('#btnSave').click(function(){
    var action = $(this).val() == '/course/update/' + courses[0].courseId;
    $('#updateForm').attr('action', action);
    $('#updateForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Add button type to submit like

`button#btnSave(type='submit') SAVE`

Comment: well, not required as he already has $('#updateForm').submit();